# How to calculate the size of an image?

Tags: images, image-processing, pixels

How many images of size 800×600 with 8-bit gray level can be stored in 512 MB of storage?

Comment: Have a look at your learning material. It's a simple multiplication.

Comment: You need to know what image format will be used.  Images are typically stored with some form of compression.  The amount depends on whether it is lossless or lossy compression, and different formats use different compression schemes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming there is no compression)

8 Bits = 1 Byte 
Therefore, the size of one pixel is 1 Byte.
Total number of pixels = 800 × 600
Total size: (800 × 600 × 1) Bytes = 480000 Bytes = 48 × 10<sup>4</sup>
Total size of storage: 512 MB = 512 × 10<sup>6</sup> bytes
Number of images that can be stored = (512 × 10<sup>6</sup>)/(48 × 10<sup>4</sup>) ≈ **1066**

---

**1066 Images**

---

Comment: 1 pixel is 3 bytes though. 1 byte for each color (red, green, blue) so it should be 800 x 600 x 3?

Comment: @Filip: Pixels can have several different color depths – OP asked about "8-bit gray level".