# How to calculate the file size for a digital image

Tags: photos, pixels, calculator

I know that there is some formula of calculating pixels x bit depth and then dividing it by another couple of numbers to get a final file size but I dont know how to do this exactly. There is a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1423664/how-to-calculate-the-size-of-an-image), but the answer seems very specific to the question.

I'd like to know how to properly calculate file sizes for digital images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I did some digging around and found a site that explains how to calculate file sizes for digital images:

**FILE SIZE** is calculated by multiplying the surface area of a document (height x width) to be scanned by the bit depth and the dpi2. Because image file size is represented in bytes, which are made up of 8 bits, divide this figure by 8

```
Formula 1 for File Size
File Size = (height x width x bit depth x dpi2) / 8
```

If the pixel dimensions are given, multiply them by each other and the bit depth to determine the number of bits in an image file. For instance, if a 24-bit image is captured with a digital camera with pixel dimensions of 2,048 x 3,072, then the file size equals (2048 x 3072 x 24)/8, or 18,874,368 bytes

```
Formula 2 for File Size
File Size = (pixel dimensions x bit depth) / 8
```

File size naming convention: Because digital images often result in very large files, the number of bytes is usually represented in increments of 210 (1,024) or more:

- 1 Kilobyte (KB) = 1,024 bytes
- 1 Megabyte (MB) = 1,024 KB
- 1 Gigabyte (GB) = 1,024 MB
- 1 Terabyte (TB) = 1,024 GB

Source can be viewed [here](http://preservationtutorial.library.cornell.edu/intro/intro-06.html)

Answer (score -1):

> but the answer seems very specific to the question.

That answer is quite general and actually you can't really get more.

> to properly calculate file sizes for digital images.

You can not. All popular formats use compression which is not really possible to predict.